C# interface implementation resolution
I'm confused with the following scenario in C# regarding the interface implementation resolution. The following code compiles without any error:
interface IA
{
    void Method();
}

class CustomAttribute : Attribute { }

interface IB : IA
{
    [Custom]
    new void Method();
}

class BaseA : IA
{
    public void Method() => Console.WriteLine("Implementation in base");
}

class B: BaseA, IB
{
    new public void Method() => Console.WriteLine("Implementation in B");
}

class C : BaseA, IB
{ 
}

Suppose that interface IA is in a 3rd party class library that we can't change, for which we are adding a custom attribute to the method in IB. I expected that Class C requires another implementation for the Method other than the one in BaseA.
My question is that why in class C the new Method implementation for IB is picked from the BaseA while it is marked new in IB?
Where in the C# specification specified to how resolve the implementation in such a case?
Does this resolving process have a name?

FWIW, you can omit both new keywords and it still builds and works (just ignore the warning about unintentional hiding).

@Dai That's right. Thanks for mentioning. It still compiles without 'new' with warnings.


Does this resolving process have a name?

That's interface mapping.
During interface mapping, the compiler always checks if base classes have an implementation of that interface member.
(Emphasis mine)

Interface mapping for a class or struct C locates an implementation for each member of each interface specified in the base class list of C. The implementation of a particular interface member I.M, where I is the interface in which the member M is declared, is determined by examining each class or struct S, starting with C and repeating for each successive base class of C, until a match is located...

If S contains a declaration of an explicit interface member implementation that matches I and M, then this member is the
implementation of I.M.

Otherwise, if S contains a declaration of a non-static public member that matches M, then this member is the implementation of
I.M. [...]



For a regular public method like BaseA.Method, there is nothing that prevents it from being mapped to both IA.Method and IB.Method.
However, if BaseA.Method were an explicit interface implementation:
class BaseA : IA
{
    void IA.Method() => Console.WriteLine("Implementation in base");
}

Then it can only be mapped to IA.Method, and class C: BaseA, IB {} would emit a compiler error.
